# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"NullPointerException

Tags: java

here is what the problem arises and here is the code that gives problem

```
private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
      int x;``
      int y;
        if (check == true)
        {
         x = evt.getX();
         xcod1 = x;

         y = evt.getY();
         ycod1 = y;
         check = false;
        }
        else
        {
         x = evt.getX();
         xcod2 = x;

         y = evt.getY();
         ycod2 = y;
         check = true;
        }
        System.out.println(xcod1+"  "+xcod2+"  "+ycod1+"  "+ycod2);
}                        



    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Graphics g = null;``
    g.drawLine(xcod1, ycod1, xcod2, ycod2);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Graphics g is `null`. You cannot dereference a `null` object (e.g. by acessing fields or methods). Dereferencing such a `null` object throws the `NullPointerException`

NullPointerException javadoc:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> Calling the instance method of a null object.
> Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

As an additonal note, don't supress null warnings unless you actually know what you are doing. The IDE/compiler is there to help you, not get in your way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for NullPointer is because the value of Graphics object is null. You need to get the Grpahics object. There are a number of ways to get it. If you want to draw the line on an image you can get it from createGraphics() method.